# knn algorithm output one result per test data

Tags: r, model, statistics, knn

I used knn to do a basic predictive model build.

After I run:

```
predictions = knn(train,test,cl,k=3)
```

and then output `predictions`, the R console has a dozen results per row.

Such as:

```
[1] Yes No Yes Yes Yes No Yes Yes Yes No No
[12] No Yes Yes Yes No No No Yes Yes Yes No
```

etc etc for 10000 rows.

I need to export this so I can match each of these results with an ID number. Ideally an export like:

```
[1] Yes
[2] No
[3] Yes
...
[10000] No
```

Is there a way in R Console to get the data to be one row per result? or just a way to straight export the results into a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go straight to a file with `write.csv`

```
write.csv(predictions, "predictions.csv")
```

Use `getwd()` to see where the file will be written.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `predictions` is a vector of length 10000. It does not have rows, what you're seeing is dependent on the width of your console.

If you want something with rows, make a data frame. If the ID number to be matched is the same as the row number (?), you could do:

```
predictions_df <- data.frame(id = 1:length(predictions), 
                             prediction = predictions,
                             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```